# How do I add external libraries to Processing?

Tags: import, processing

I am unable to add external libraries to processing.

I've followed multiple tutorials and looked at other Stackoverflow questions but none of them do the job.

I've unzipped the library and put it into the libraries folder inside of Processing, but it still hasn't worked, I have tried with 2 different libraries, the main focus being P5irebase.

https://github.com/barneyElDinosaurio/P5ireBase

I expect the examples to show up, and to also have the option to import the library, but none of that ever shows up. No contributed libraries in the import library section under the Sketches button, and no examples for contributed libraries under libraries which is under the File button.

Processing Forum Link: https://discourse.processing.org/t/how-do-i-add-external-libraries-to-processing/12750

All help is appreciated! Thanks :)

EDIT: After changing P5ireBase-master to just P5ireBase I get the error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\reedm\Documents\Processing\libraries\P5ireBase (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at processing.app.Util.copyFile(Util.java:130)
    at processing.app.Sketch.addFile(Sketch.java:1355)
    at processing.app.ui.Editor$FileDropHandler.importData(Editor.java:480)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$DropHandler.drop(TransferHandler.java:1544)
    at java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.drop(DropTarget.java:455)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$SwingDropTarget.drop(TransferHandler.java:1282)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:538)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchDropEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:852)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:776)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetEvent.dispatch(SunDropTargetEvent.java:48)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processDropTargetEvent(Container.java:4609)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4471)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw in your Processing forum link that you tried to drag&drop the library into Processing IDE and you've got this error :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\main\Documents\Processing\libraries\P5ireBase-master

You see the "-master" at the end of your Library folder ? Well, it comes from GitHub and indicates the code branch you downloaded. Juts remove it from the folder name and your library should work as expected.

With Processing, you're library folder must always have the same name of the main .jar file in the "library" folder. So in your case, P5ireBase.

I hope that's the only issue and that everything works fine now for you.

Comment: First of all thanks! I now know that it can't find the file, but what happened now? I edited my answer to show what happened, have you been able to install the library yourself (of course you don't have to if you wouldn't like to). Once, more thanks so much! P.S. I'm going to try going onto an administrator account.

Comment: Also, it says (Access is denied) which according to: http://craftingjava.blogspot.com/2012/05/file-not-found-exception-file-not-found.html means it is a read only file? Could it be because I am not administrator (still have to try that)?